POST request in login page, not logging in
Hi I want to log in https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-co/niv/users/sign_in via python with a POST request, i am not a pro,  i am guiding myself with forums, chatgpt, friends, but it is not working.
I wrote a python code where I get the html information on the webpage, then send the post request, after the post login request I make a get request to another link but when I see the response.text, is the same html of the login page and not the one that should appear after logging in. Help, what am I doing wrong?
# Get the login page to fetch CSRF token and initial cookies
login_url = 'https://ais.usvisa-info.com/es-co/niv/users/sign_in'
url = 'https://ais.usvisa-info.com/es-co/niv/schedule/54777814/payment'
page = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Assuming the CSRF token is in a meta tag (common in Rails apps)
csrf_token = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'})['content'] if soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'}) else None

print(csrf_token)
login_data = {
   # 'authenticity_token': csrf_token,  # the CSRF token you extracted
    'user[email]': 'betomolinares0315@gmail.com',
    'user[password]': 'AlbertoMolinares132*',
    'policy_confirmed': '1',  # Check this based on how the site handles it
    'commit': 'Iniciar sesión'  # This may or may not be needed; depends on how the server processes it
}

# # Include the CSRF token in your request if it exists
# if csrf_token:
#     login_data['authenticity_token'] = csrf_token

headers = {
    'Referer': login_url,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

cookies = page.cookies
response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)


# Check if login was successful
if response.ok:
    print("Logged in successfully!")
else:
    print("Failed to log in")

#..... more code omited because the important thing to be done is above.

The response is positive and it is printed the Logged in successfully! , But when I see the response.text, it shows the same login page. Help please.
The credentials in the code is a test account, it can be used freely.

You should check the status code returned.  It might indicate a redirect, etc.
